# Connecting to jndi within websphere error

Tags: java, jpa, deployment, compiler-errors, websphere-liberty

I'm in a little debacle and was looking at any assistance

I have a simple JPA application that is connected to a database and am receiving an error in websphere that I'm failing to understand.

```
[1/25/16 10:55:46:950 CST] 0000001c SystemOut 0  CalSMTJPA  INFO
[WebContainer : 0] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.1-SNAPSHOT+OPENJPA-679-Final 
[1/25/16 10:55:46:950 CST] 0000001c SystemOut O 15  CalSMTJPA  INFO   [WebContainer : 0] 
openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "com.ibm.ws.persistence.jdbc.sql.SQLServerDictionary" (Microsoft SQL Server 11.00.5058 ,Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 2.0 2.0.1803.100). 
[1/25/16 10:55:46:950 CST] 0000001c servlet E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: 
Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /Home.jsp in application CalSMTEAR. 
Exception created : <openjpa-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT+OPENJPA-679-Final-r422266:746282 nonfatal general error>

****org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: For input string: "JDBC"****

at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:196)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:142)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:192)
at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:42)
at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:27)
at entities.controller.PlatformsManager.getEntityManager(PlatformsManager.java:43)
at entities.controller.PlatformsManager.getPlatforms(PlatformsManager.java:136)
at com.ibm._jsp._Home._jspService(_Home.java:90)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1461)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:793)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:444)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:234)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:337)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3622)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:927)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1566)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:175)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "JDBC"

Comment: Please check if [this](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/135062/srve0068e-an-exception-was-thrown-by-one-of-the-service-methods-of-the-servlet-equinoxbridgeservlet) or [that](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK92140) links helps

Answer (score 3):

The error from OpenJPA appears to be caused by it incorrectly trying to use the dictionary for MS SQLServer to connect to the database you're using.  If you're specifying the

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value=" org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLServerDictionary "/>
```

property in your persistence.xml, you need to update that with the correct dictionary for the database and driver you're using, see http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.1/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_dbsetup_dbsupport.html for details.  If you're not specifying the property in your persistence.xml and letting OpenJPA try to auto-detect it, try specifying the property in your persistence.xml and assign it the appropriate value for the database vendor to which you're connecting.